# PHP Module - Variable Wont Set

Tags: php, oop, variables, module

I'm pretty newish to modular programming.

I'm having trouble setting a variable in a module, but only in particular functions.

I have (useless stuff removed):

```
class Products extends Modules {

  private $resultsFound;

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function getResultsFound() {
    return $this->resultsFound;
  }

  private function setResultsFound($resultsFound) {
    $this->resultsFound = $resultsFound;
  }

}
```

I have 2 public functions in the module, both do near enough the same thing, but one will set the var with `$this->setResultsFound(12)` and one won't.

```
public function sortSearchBar($categoryID, $brandID, $sort = false, $limit = false, $search = false){
    foreach ($this->sortAwway as $key => $val) {
        $optionItems[] = '<option value="'.$key.'"'. (($sort == $key) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) .'>'.$this->htmlspecialchars($val).'</option>';
    }

    foreach ($this->searchLimit as $key => $val) {
        $limitItems[] = '<option value="'.$key.'"'. (($limit == $key) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) .'>'.$this->htmlspecialchars($val).'</option>';
    }
    $this->setResultsFound(12); //works

    return '
    <form action=...
    </form>';
}

public function showProductItemList($categoryID, $brandID = false, $page, $sort = false, $limit = false, $search = false, $cleanURL = true){

    //echo $this->echoArray($this->getProductsForCategory($categoryID, $brandID));
    $q = $this->getProductsForCategory($categoryID, $brandID, $sort, $search);

    $this->setResultsFound(12); //doesn't work

    return $this->formatProductResults($q, $limit, $cleanURL, $page);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why?

Cheers,
Rhys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I think that the `setResultsFound()` method should probably be declared `protected`, not `private`.

[Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. It's a problem I've not seen before. Even setting it to public had no change.

Comment: How is it that you are certain it doesn't work? I'm just wondering if something about the way you are calling `showProductItemList()` is causing the value to be altered after it has executed.

Comment: You are right. It seems to be setting and not calling from the public get function, unless I call it from outside the module. I'll get some more work done on visibility. Thanks.